# How to use empty list when we have an empty list anyways

Tags: java, list

This question is a bit hard to explain so please look at the `increasingPath` function in the code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42396/path-from-source-to-destination-with-increasing-values). Now assuming the path `does not` exist, and arraylist `pointPath` with 0 size is returned.
However I have read that we must use Collections.emptyList, but how do I use it in this scenario, when I already have a probably empty list called `pointPath` ? If not to use `Collections.emptyList` then when to use it ?

Comment: Please avoid reliance on link to external sites and include all relevant information within your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're supposed to do is use Collections.EmptyList for comparisons and returning.

for example:

```
if (pointPath.equals(Collections.emptyList()){
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

I don't think it changes how your program will execute, but it makes the code readable and self-documenting.

Answer (score 1):

Simply check

```
if (pointPath.isEmpty()){
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

The only difference from actually returning a your list that is accidentally empty is that `Collections.emptyList()` is immutable list. If that is not of any value to you, I'd return your real list. That way there is less code to read.